# Android: Accept data from other apps

Tags: android

I am working on article reader and am trying to accept article urls from other apps (similar to how Pocket, Evernote are listed in the Share via menu as "Add to X").

My activity contains the following in the manifest:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAUlT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

But so far the app only shows up in the "Share via" list for Chrome(Android), but not for other apps that show articles (for example, it doesn't show up in the share list in the "Reddit Now" app whereas other apps like "Pocket" or "Evernote" do).

What do I have to specify to accept any kind of information that may potentially contain an article url?

Comment: Use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept&hl=en to see what intent is being sent by these apps to see if your intent filter is not "too narrow"

Comment: My app is listed as one of the "activities that match this intent" when I use the "Intent Intercept" app, yet it doesn't show up in the "share via" list.